# android - Bottom Sheet Fragment with margins and collapsed height

Tags: android, material-design

My class extends from `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and is working fine by now. But I dont get it how to set the collapsed height (`setPeekHeight` on BottomSheet Behavior).

Another thing I want to know is: How to set the margin left and right only when the BottomSheet is collapsed? Like this screenshots below.

collapsed:

[image: collapsed]

expanded:

[image: expanded]